# Celery with SQS sending message but not executing task

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I've configured celery to call to SQS and when I check the queue on the AWS console the message count increases. However the tasks themselves do not run, I see some errors in `/var/log/celery-worker.log` that gives off this:

```
[2016-09-08 01:24:24,940: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 26.00 seconds...

[2016-09-08 01:24:50,960: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 28.00 seconds...

[2016-09-08 01:25:18,997: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 30.00 seconds...

[2016-09-08 01:25:49,030: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 32.00 seconds...

[2016-09-08 01:26:21,069: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 32.00 seconds...

[2016-09-08 01:26:53,111: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 32.00 seconds...
```

I'm confused, the broker is contacting SQS properly, so why is it not activating the task, the worker is running locally on the same machine. This is all an elasticbeanstalk instance using django.

Comment: How have you set up the authentication for celery to connect to the SQS are you using AWS Secret keys?

Comment: @error2007s Yes, inside my `settings.py` file I have both my regular and secret key configured. The SQS queue was created by the django/celery instance, so I know that part must be functioning.

Comment: And this port 5672 is it open in sec group?

Comment: @error2007s is it the sec group the beanstalk instance is part of? The SQS itself doesn't seem to have a sec group.

Comment: I was facing the same error I was using AWS CLI for communication between celery and SQS and my AWS key got deleted by mistake so when I updated those keys that issue got fixed I was facing same error in logs Cannot connect to amqp

Comment: @error2007s My keys I don't think are deleted, how did you fix it? The keys are in my `settings.py` but I can try exporting them in a post launch script as well.

Comment: My keys were at ~/.aws/config I changed them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122870/discussion-between-dylan-lawrence-and-error2007s).

Comment: @DylanLawrence did you come upon a fix for this? Mind adding an answer for how you did this?

Comment: I am having the same issues working with airflow Airflow is using celeryExecutor

The scheduler is calling celery and is able to write to SQS, however, the worker is not able to connect to SQS, any help will be appreciated